# What could you do with a PTR record of "localhost"?

Tags: dns

In today's log summary from my SSH server, I found the following interesting entry:

```
Illegal users from:
  113.175.205.167 (localhost): 2 times
```

Doing a DNS lookup on `113.175.205.167` does indeed resolve to `localhost` (a DNS lookup of `localhost` resolves to `127.0.0.1`, as expected).  What could an attacker be trying to do with such an obviously-invalid DNS record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attacker could try to **bypass a hostname-based whitelist** on your server.

In a naive scenario, you might configure SSH or a firewall to only allow connections from `"localhost"`, intending to lock out all remote machines for security reasons.

A *smart* SSH server would recognize that `113.175.205.167` is remote and block the connection attempt. Eventually, it would resolve `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and see that the IPs don't match.

However, a server with a flawed implementation might first conduct a reverse DNS lookup of the IP, find the `localhost` entry, and reason that the hostnames match, thus allowing the connection.

*NB: Resolving `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` is obviously done internally in most cases, skipping the DNS query (e.g. by looking it up in `/etc/hosts`). Hence, a malicious DNS server cannot easily attack the other way round by resolving `localhost` to an arbitrary IP.*

### Why does that particular IP resolve to localhost?

Here, it's likely not part of an attack, but because that IP is located in Hanoi and apparently, "[The Country of Vietnam Resolves to Localhost](https://blog.shodan.io/the-country-of-vietnam-resolves-to-localhost/)". The [reason](http://www.mounirorfi.com/blog/2015/02/18/why-vietnam-resolves-to-localhost/) seems to be an outdated technique to bypass e-mail spam filters.